# Implementing HeartRate sensor on Android Studio

Tags: class, android-studio

I'm writing a wearable app that uses the HeartRate sensor, specifically for Moto 360. I'm not sure which  sensor to use ( http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html ). Or does HeartRate sensor has its own class? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can [retrieve available Heart Rate sensors](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_HEART_RATE) through the [Sensor API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html).

Use `SensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE)` to get a list of Heart Rate sensors available.

> The reported value is the heart rate in beats per minute.

The application must have the `android.permission.BODY_SENSORS` permission to retrieve data from, or know of the existence of, any heart rate sensors.